# Issue with parsing JSON data stored as string in Scala variable

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hdfs, scheduled-tasks

Environment : Spark 1.6, Scala

Through an API call, I stored JSON data in the variable "rawdata" using curl in Scala. Saved content of the variable as a file in HDFS. Now I want to parse and create table from variable (rawdata) data, as it already contains data as string (rather than reading saved file from HDFS). I have tried the following way but got error. I am using Scheduler to get updated records with 30 sec interval. Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

```
object ConnTest extends App {

  val conf = new SparkConf()
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf.setAppName("Spark Ingestion").setMaster("local[*]"))
  val hivecontext = new HiveContext(sc)

  var run_id = java.time.LocalDate.now
  val format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMddHHmmss")

  val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  val scheduler = actorSystem.scheduler
  val task = new Runnable {
    def run() {
      val dt = format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
      println(dt)

      val writeFilePath="vlinkAlarm_" + dt+".json"
      val rdd1=sc.parallelize(jsonWriter(writeFilePath))**// ERROR No Spark Context**
      rdd1.foreach(println)
    }
  }

  implicit val executor = actorSystem.dispatcher

  scheduler.schedule(
    initialDelay = Duration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    interval = Duration(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    runnable = task)


  val uri="hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020"
  val conf1 = new Configuration()
  conf.set("fs.defaultFS", uri)
  val fs = FileSystem.get(conf1)

  def jsonWriter(fileName: String): String = {
  println(fileName)
    val rawdata = "curl http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/USA/all"!!
rawdata
  }
  }
```

====Error===

```
16/12/13 15:53:25 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.

20161213155329
vlinkAlarm_20161213155329.json
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 44013    0 44013    0     0  68060      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 68026
[ERROR] [12/13/2016 15:53:30.532] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [TaskInvocation] Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:
```

and after sometime

```
The currently active SparkContext was created at:

(No active SparkContext.)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:
```

My Json data looks like

```
{
    "results": [{
        "id": "6475867",
        "date": "2016-12-09",
        "time": "16:50:49",
        "varbinds": ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    }, {
        "id": "6475866",
        "date": "2016-12-09",
        "time": "16:50:05",
        "varbinds": ["4", "192.255.54.154:1136", "CASAH 4", "52", "6", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    }]
}
```

Thanks
Hossain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not exactly solved this problem, but found workaround. Just used Thread inside loop instead of Scheduler. Used following code to parse Json stored as string in variable rawdata.

```
for (i<- 1 to 10){
val url = "http://10.51.253.11:8082/vistalink/1/alarm.json?isVerbose=true"
    val rawdata = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString

val RDDFromString = sc.parallelize(rawdata :: Nil)
    val DF = hivecontext.read.json(RDDFromString)

DF.printSchema()
Thread.sleep(1000*30)
}
```

Thanks
Hossain